# Should exceptions be used to unwinding process back to main?

Tags: java, exception, design-patterns

Now this is really quite difficult for me to explain so please bear with me.

I've been wondering as of late the best way to "unwind" every chained method back to a main method when certain circumstances are met. For example, say I make a call to a method from Main and from that method I call another one and so on. At some point I may want to cancel all further operations of every method that is chained and simply return to the Main method. What is the best way to do this?

I'll give a scenario:

In the following code there are 3 methods, however when Method1 calls Method2 with a null value it should unwind all the way back to Main without further operations in Method2 (EG the "Lots of other code" section).

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    try
    {
        Method1();
    }
    catch( ReturnToMainException e )
    {
        // Handle return \\
    }
}

public static void Method1() throws ReturnToMainException
{
    String someString = null;
    Method2( someString  );

    // Lots more code after here
}

public static boolean Method2( String someString )
{
    if( someString == null )
        throw new ReturnToMainException();
    else if( someString.equals( "Correct" ))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

In this example I use a throw which I've read should only be used in "Exceptional Circumstances". I often run into this issue and find myself simply doing If/Else statements to solve the issue, but when dealing with methods that can only return True/False I find I don't have enough options to return to decide on an action. I guess I could use Enumerators or classes but that seems somewhat cumbersome.

Comment: I think "unwind" is more appropriate than "cascade".

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Yeah you're probably right :)

Comment: Another point is that you have inconsistent return types. You could return the booean to the first method but would then what?

Comment: "uncascade" ? "decascade" ? Whatever you call it, either an exception (as you have), or just returns with correct result handling (e.g. if Method2() returns false then Method1() returns and you're back in main() just like you wanted...)

Comment: If you suddenly, from deep inside a call stack, decide that processing should be aborted, how is that not an "exception"? Something is wrong (i.e. not correct/valid to process further) and current processing must be aborted. Isn't that the very definition of an "Exceptional Circumstance"?

Comment: Why do you want to return to `main`, instead of to the place where `Method2` was called with a null parameter (i.e. `Method1`)?

Comment: This was just a quick example for the question. In my scenario method1 could be a Login method and Method2 be a username authentication method. If username authentication encounters some kind of issue, it may need to abort. This is just a hypothetical scenario to try and show my point though.

Comment: If Java had supported it, would you have used a goto statement instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I use a throw which I've read should only be used in "Exceptional Circumstances". I often run into this issue and find myself simply doing If/Else statements to solve the issue

Exception throwing is relatively expensive so it should not be used without careful thought but I believe that your example is a ok example of proper usage.

In general, you should use exceptions only for "exceptional" behavior of the program.  If `someString` can be `null` through some sort of user input, database values, or other normal mechanism then typically you should handle that case with normal return mechanisms if possible.

In your case, you could return a `Boolean` object (not a primitive) and return `null` if `someString` is null.

```
private static Boolean method2( String someString ) {
     if (someString == null) {
         return null;
     }
     ...
}
```

Then you would handle the `null` appropriately in the caller maybe returning a `boolean` to `main` based on whether or not the method "worked".

```
private static boolean method1() {
    ...
    Boolean result = method2(someString);
    if (result == null) {
        // the method didn't "work"
        return false;
    }
```

Then in main you can see if `method1` "worked":

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (!method1()) {
        // handle error
    }
    ...
}
```

Notice that I downcased your method names and changed the permissions of your methods to `private` both which are good patterns.

> Enumerators or classes but that seems somewhat cumbersome.

Yeah indeed.  It depends a bit on how this code is used.  If it is a API method that is called by others, you might want to return some sort of `Result` class which might provide feedback like a `boolean` that the argument was `null`.  Or you might throw an `IllegalArgumentException` in that case.   Instead, if this is an internal local private method, then I'd vote for a simpler way of handling argument errors.  Either way I'd use javadocs to document the behavior so you don't trip up future you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Though I worded things badly you seemed to pick up my points exactly. I pretty much expected your answers but wasn't sure if I was missing something valuable. I appreciate your reply and it has given me some piece of mind :) Also I've picked up a bad habit lately of uppercased method names (From c# I believe)